# How can i follow Google's "I feel lucky" redirect url?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use curl in order to follow this google redirection, but i cannot retrieve the final (terminal) url:

http://www.google.com/webhp#q=stackoverflow&btnI

Can anyone help?

I'm using the curl function from php website:

```
function get_final_url( $url, $timeout = 5 )
{
$url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );

if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302)
{
    ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3)     Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
    $headers = get_headers($response['url']);

    $location = "";
    foreach( $headers as $value )
    {
        if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
            return get_final_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
    }
}

if (    preg_match("/window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) ||
        preg_match("/window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value)
)
{
    return get_final_url ( $value[1] );
}
else
{
    return $response['url'];
}
}

echo get_final_url("http://www.google.com/webhp#q=stackoverflow&btnI");
```

The result that I'm getting is (which is also the input):

http://www.google.com/webhp#q=stackoverflow&btnI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try another url:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&btnI=
```

This will return a 302 response.

Comment: curious how it for me doesn't work the same with `http://www.google.com/search?q=stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString&btnI=` (apple obj-c api docs). I thought it was always 1st result but maybe there's some internal "confidence" var ass-well -_-